# How can I create a Primary Zone NOT integrated with Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2016, dns-server

Using Powershell on Windows Server Core I'm [administering DNS Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=win10-ps) from a fresh install.

After adding a Primary Zone using a backing Zone File,

`Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -ZoneName "example.com" -ZoneFile "example.com.dns" -verbose -passthru;`

it reports results as "AD integrated", seen in this message:

```
VERBOSE: Adding DNS primary (AD integrated/file-backed forward/reverse lookup) zone example.com on DNS1 server.
VERBOSE: AllowUpdate successfully set on server DNS1.

ZoneName                            ZoneType        IsAutoCreated   IsDsIntegrated  IsReverseLookupZone  IsSigned
--------                            --------        -------------   --------------  -------------------  --------
example.com                         Primary         False           False           False                False
```

The backing zone file is indeed created at `c:\windows\system32\dns\example.com.dns`

So, is this messaging telling me that it's integrated with AD already (or possible), and if integrated already how can I create the zone without AD integration?

When Googling for an answer I keep finding articles about "Active Directory Integrated DNS Zone", however I can't find info about how to administer the zone outside of AD or separate it from AD.

My impression is the `-ZoneFile` param should keep the zone out of AD along with creating the DNS file on disk; however I'm not sure how to confirm the zone is indeed not inside AD.

Comment: IsDsIntegrated shows as false. You can verify this by running Get-DnsServerZone in Powershell.

Comment: @joeqwerty Does "DS Integrated" then mean AD Integrated?

Comment: Yes............